# What is difference between references and objects in java?

Tags: java, object, reference

I have class GUI so I can create object like this:

```
GUI g1 = new GUI();
```

and a reference variable like this:

```
GUI g2;
```

Now as much as I know, g2 is a reference variable which gives reference to GUI class and g1 is an object of GUI class. What is the difference between g1 and g2? I can use property of GUI class with object but what is the possible usage of g2?

Comment: I think you cannot use g2 in your code, because it has been not initialized yet and it's null.

Comment: I think this question deserves a nice answer to keep around!

Comment: @SantiagoLezica thanks mate.first someone down voted this question.

Comment: if i create variable `GUI g2` does this mean it must be an object of class GUI?

Comment: @OP no problem man! This is what SO is for, and should someone in the future wonder the same thing you did, they should be able to stumble upon something meaningful!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

References are names. Objects are stuff. You can have different names for stuff, even for stuff that doesn't actually exist.

You can declare names, without actually giving them any "real" meaning, like this:

```
GUI g1;
```

You can assign meaning (real stuff to refer to) to names with the = operator:

```
GUI g1 = some_gui;
```

Names can change their meaning over time. The same name can refer to different things at different points in history.

```
GUI g1 = some_gui;

doSomething();

g1 = some_other_gui;
```

There are also synonyms: multiple names can refer to the same thing:

```
GUI g2 = g1;
```

That's pretty much what references do. They are names meant to refer to stuff.

Stuff can be created:

```
new GUI();
```

Stuff can be created and named on the spot for later reference (literally!):

```
GUI g1 = new GUI();
```

And stuff can be referred to, using its name (or any of its names!):

```
g1.doSomething();
g2.doSomethingAgain();
```

Different stuff of the same kind (Class) can be created, and named differently:

```
GUI g1 = new GUI();
GUI g2 = new GUI();
GUI g3 = new GUI();

GUI g1_synonym = g1;
```

:)

Comment: Great first paragraph. Good way to introduce OOP ideas.

Answer (score 23):

> What is difference between references and objects in java?

A reference is an entity which provides a way to access object of its type. An object is an entity which provides a way to access the members of it's class or type.

Generally, You can't access an object without a reference to it.

```
class GUI
{
    void aMethod()
    {
        // some business logic.
    }
}
```

You can call `aMethod` with or without a reference. but you definitely need an object.

Without Reference:

```
new GUI().aMethod(); 
// you can't reuse the object
// bad way to code.
```

With Reference:

```
GUI aGUIReference = new GUI();
aGUIReference.aMethod();
// Now, the object can be reused.
// Preferred way to code
```

---

Now a little explanation to your code lines:

```
GUI g1 = new GUI();
// g1 is a reference to an object of GUI class.

GUI g2;
// g2 is a reference that can point to an object of GUI class
// but currently not pointing to any.
```

The only difference b/w `g1` and `g2` is that `g1` is initialized with an object but `g2` points to `null`

```
g2 = g1;
// it means g2 will point to the same object g1 is pointing to
// only one object but two references.
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

You are not able to use `g2` until you assign an object to it, since currently it does not point to any object, while `g1` already points to a `GUI` object and you may use it.

This:

```
GUI g1 = new GUI();
```

is pretty much equivalent to:

```
GUI g1;
g1 = new GUI();
```

Answer (score 4):

`References` are sort of pointers to a block of memory called `objects.`

```
GUI g1 = new GUI();
```

For explanation, let me break the above statement.

```
GUI g1;
g1 = new GUI();
```

1st step: `g1` is a reference variable (pointer), not yet pointing to any valid memory location.

2nd Step: The second step allocates the memory for object of class `GUI` and the assignment operation make the reference variable `g1` point to this object (memory location).
The `new` keyword allocates the memory for the object of class `GUI`.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are like bubbles floating through a space called heap. Variables are merely links to these bubbles. The expression `new GUI()` creates an object and `=` operator links it to the variable `g1`. `g2` is also a variable but it's not linked to any object. You can easily swap them by writing

```
g2 = g1;
g1 = null;
```

Now `g2` refers to the object that `g1` was referring to in the beginning, and `g1` refers to nothing. The object is intact, only the variables was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Both, g1 and g2 are references. But g2 is not initialized, so couldn't be used in code.

```
//Tells that g1 g2 should hold Gui object. Currently they are not holding any object.
Gui g1;
Gui g2;

//Now g1 reference holds object. g2 reference still doesn't point to any object.
g1 = new GUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Java name of your variable is a reference (except of primitive types). You can't use `g2` because it was not been initialized and even is not null. You'll get a compile time error trying to call a method for g2. After `GUI g2;` g2 is not pointing to an object in the memory. If you set `g2` to null like this `GUI g2 = null;` you can use it after declaration but if you call a method for g2 you'll get a run time NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

A reference is a "hook" where you can hang an object on.
An object may be on more than one hook.