# What does null pointer exception mean in error messages?

Tags: java, pointers, nullpointerexception

There are many articles asking to help with their code but not many actually answer what this means. Java doesn't use pointers on the user side but I get a null pointer exception error in my Java code sometimes and it made me wonder.. Does Java use pointers behind the scenes?

Or is this just a term that is used to describe a definition error.

Comment: it means that the reference you have created for an object has null in it... or the object is not initialized...

Comment: Please consider to search stackoverflow first before posting a question.

Comment: read the documentation: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: [What is difference between references and objects in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247886/what-is-difference-between-references-and-objects-in-java) or [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Null pointer means not using pointer concept java is object based so object is not creating means its memory is null so its returns null pointer exception don't true translate java language words .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't use pointers, but uses references. `NullPointerException` is a way to say that an attempt is made to send a message (invoke a method) using reference which doesn't point to any object. It has nothing to do with pointers in the sense of C/C++.